# How to hyperlink to html

Tags: javascript, html, flask, hyperlink

Please help, I have provided below three files: `application.py`, `ask.html`, and `link.html`. In `ask.html`, I'm trying to ask the user to provide me a link. They will then be redirected to `link.html` where there is a button to take them to that link. But once the button is pressed, it doesn't take me to the link, comes out error 404 not found.

In application.py:

```
@app.route("/")
def ask():
    return render_template("ask.html")

@app.route("/link")
def link():
    weblink = request.args.get("weblink")
    return render_template("link.html", weblink=weblink)
```

In ask.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Ask</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="/link">
            <input placeholder="weblink here" name="weblink" type="text">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

In link.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Ask</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="{{ weblink }}" class="btn btn-primary">Go to Link</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *"comes out error"* .. always provide all specific details for errors

Comment: Thanks, i've specified it as error 404

Answer (score 0):

First, change:

```
<form action="/link">
```

to:

```
<form action="/link" method="post">
```

Then, in `link()`:

```
@app.route("/link", methods = [“GET”, “POST”])
def link():
    weblink = request.form.get("weblink")
    ...
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for sharing, however  the same problem still comes up though. the button just brought me to a /None directory, but still error 404

Comment: Hmm, you should have received a 405 - method not allowed because I forgot to add methods to /link. See edit

Comment: Are you remembering to type over the “web link here” placeholder?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
  <form action="/link">
```

To

```
<form action = "{{url_for('link')}}" method = "post">
```

in application.py
change

```
@app.route('/link')
```

to

```
@app.route('/link', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def link():
    if request.method == 'POST':
          weblink = request.form.get('weblink')
          return render_template('link.html', weblink=weblink)
```